# Psycopg2 does not recognize the DB I want to drop

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I tried to write a function to drop database :

```
def deleteDb(self, dbName: str):
    conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname="postgres", user="postgres")
    conn.autocommit = True
    curs = conn.cursor()
    curs.execute("DROP DATABASE {};".format(dbName))
    curs.close()
    conn.close()
```

When I try to test it with an existing db :

```
def test_deleteDb(self):
    self.deleteDb("dbTest")
```

I get this error :
"psycopg2.errors.InvalidCatalogName: database "dbtest" does not exist"

I tried to play with the isolation level, to drop all the connections to the database and to connect directly to the database but it did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember to put quotes around identifiers that contain upper-case letters:

```
curs.execute('DROP DATABASE "{}";'.format(dbName))
```

Note that string substitution into SQL-statements is generally a bad idea beause it is vulnerable to SQL-injection.